# How to override the BSOD behavior in Windows systems

Tags: windows, boot, bsod, kernel, setup

Many times , when I was re-installing Windows in an old computer, I faced the famous BSOD and the system argues that it must shutdown to prevent "further harms" to the hardware : in my humble opinion,this is a paranoiac behaviour and rather unjustified ;
Now that i'm stuck in reinitializing some old XP machine , I wonder whether it would be possible to bypass the BSOD through a driver or even patching the kernel so that the system ignores some hardware errors and continue the boot process ?

Edit:

when using a linux live cd or even the miniXP of HBCD the system starts successfully but i want to use the old PC with Windows - i even removed the HDD and when XP begins the installation process ,it asks me to check the installed hard disk or remove any newly installed devices !
I checked the memory : nothing to complain about

in my opinion , the OS should be more fault-tolerant (if there is really some faults ...) and since my question received a very negative feedback,we could be more productive,do anyone know where that BSOD behavior is coded ? i think that some kernel-level driver inserted at the beginining (e.g : through floppy disk) could rectify this behavior

Comment: Do you do complete HDD diagnostic tests for these old computers?

Comment: Rewriting the Windows OS is beyond the scope of tjhis site.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The BSOD behaviour isn't some "choice" by the operating system to protect against some frivolous program going awry. You see a BSOD because some data structure or operation critical to the entire functionality of the system has gone wrong and rather than doing anything from simply rebooting to overwriting your entire hard drive with zeroes it has chosen to halt operation and tell you what went wrong. If you see a BSOD with any regularity then you should be looking at your hardware and software to determine where the fault lies. Calling it "paranoid" is massively underestimating the problem.

Comment: ***"... but i want to use the old PC with Windows..."***, I think that it would be helpful for you that instead of asking a question about an impossible task of "outsmarting" the Windows OS, you should just ask another question about your issue installing Windows XP (it seems that you have such an issue, but the details aren't clear, and anyway it's a completely different question from what you asked here.)

Answer (score 3):

While it's correct that the BSOD used to say ***...Windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer*** it's not an accurate description of what's happening.

When a BSOD happens it means that something the system needs to be able to work doesn't work and the system can't function further. Therefore it restarts.

And indeed on the newer BSOD screens they worded it differently to indicate that it's the problem that make the PC in need to restart and not simply because they want to crash it (it's the same type of things still causing the BSODs):
[image]

Of course there can hypothetically be an OS programmed not to care if it can do it's critical functions, but every normal OS does care, and there is no way to rewrite the Windows OS.